# Get the right class in base of an argument - Pattern

Tags: design-patterns, domain-driven-design

I have a little doubt on about get a class in base of an object passed to a function.
In my case, I can two different types of object: classA, classB that have the same interface. 
I have to pass one of that object to a service and get its repository.
I have thought something like this:

```
classA implements MyInterface {
...
}
classB implements MyInterface {
...
}

class MyService () 
{
   private $strategy;

   public function __construct(Strategy $strategy)
   {
      $this->strategy = $strategy;
   }

   public function execute(MyInterface $object)
   {
      $repository = $this->strategy->getRepository($object);
   }
}

class Strategy
{
    private $repoA;
    provate $repoB;

    public function __construct(ClassARepository $repoA, ClassBRepository $repoB)
    {
        $this->repoA = $repoA;
        $this->repoB = $repoB;
    }

    public function getRepository(MyInterface $object)
    {
        if ($object::class === 'classA') {
           return $this->repoA;
        }

        if ($object::class === 'classB') {
           return $this->repoB;
        }

        throw new DomainException('Invalid Class');
    }
}
```

So I have created a service that with an if condition decides which repository comes back. Is this correct? Or there is a cleanest and right code?
 Thanks

Answer (score 1):

My suspicion is that there is a better way to design this system (though without knowing specifically what you are trying to accomplish, I cannot be sure). It defeats the purpose of using an interface if the "callee" needs to know the concrete type in order to carry out its logic. It is the *implementer* of an interface that should be given responsibility for carrying out *implementation* details.

For example, how can your `Service::execute` method know what to *do* with the `Repository` it retrieves? What do the next 5 lines of that method look like? It is not clear in your example whether or not each `Repository` implements a common interface.

If they do not, then your `Service` will suffer from the need for control-flow statements to disambiguate the object type as well (which kind of defeats the purpose). In this case it would make more sense to simply create a `Service` per object in addition to a `Repository` per object. This would remove the need for any sort of control-flow based on object types altogether.

If each `Repository` *does* implement a common interface, then it would make more sense to push the "strategy" portion of your logic down into the `Repository` (e.g. `Repository::save(MyInterface $object)`).

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach that cleans up the getRepository logic is to use a dictionary/hash-table to store the repositories.

The key to the dictionary could be the type/class of the instance, and the value stored would be the repository.  This approach does not require code changes (as in a new if block) when a new type is introduced.

Your CTOR would also then be changed to take in a more flexible collection of repositories (ex. a collection of tuples for initialization of the dictionary).

Answer (score 0):

The problem that I see with this implementation is that your `Strategy` class holds one attribute for each concrete class that implements `MyInterface`. If later you want to add a `Class C` then you will need to change the `Strategy` class as a side effect.

This design can be improved with the creation of a more flexible data structure to hold the concrete classes. You could create a hash map attribute and receive a list of `MyInterface` on the constructor per example.